# PHP array_flip() Bug?

Tags: php, arrays

The weirdest thing is happening to me...

I have a form I'm sending via an ajax post (using jquery's serialize function) to a php script running this function (stripped down for clarity):

```
            $arr = $_POST;
            unset($arr['command']);
            unset($arr['index']);
            $vals = $arr;
            $keys = $arr;


            $keys = array_flip($keys);

            return 'vals= ' . implode(',',$vals) . '      keys = ' . implode(',',$keys);
```

The String I sent that works looks like this...

[image]

that gives me the result...

[image]

now when I Remove the "S" from "About" (in the title field) I get the data string that looks like this:
[image]

that gives me THIS result:
[image]

The "Title" key has been completely stripped out of the equation!

Any Ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While flipping an array if a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its values, and all others will be lost.

An example(from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php))

```
<?php
$trans = array("a" => 1, "b" => 1, "c" => 2);
$trans = array_flip($trans);
print_r($trans);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

Comment: On unrelated note, PHP also has array_keys() function, if you need all the array keys as values.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip) is not just returning an array of the array keys. Instead, it flips the mapping of *key* → *value* to *value* → *key*. And when an array with duplicate values is flipped, only the latest key will be used:

> If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its values, and all others will be lost.

Now if you just want the array keys, use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) instead.

Comment: I gave an upvote for pointing out array_keys... coaddict answered my question first so I had to give him the checkmark, but thank you.